# How to use loaded h2o model in fastshap in R?

Tags: r, h2o, shap

I want to use fastshap with h2o model. But there are lots of difficult things that I have to solve.
I load completed model, and use predict_contribusions function.

Here's part of my code.

```
# data: dataXY
library(h2o)
h2o.init(bind_to_localhost = F)

# data split
data.hex <- as.h2o(dataXY)
splits <- h2o.splitFrame(data.hex,ratios=c(0.6,0.2),seed=1234)
train <- splits[[1]]
valid <- splits[[2]]
test <- splits[[3]]

# load model from server
Basemodel <- h2o.loadModel(path)
pred <- predict_contrbutions.H2OModel(Basemodel, newdata = train)
explainer <- explain(Basemodel, X = train, pred_wrapper = pred, newdata = test[1], nsim = 1)
```

Then, some error is generated.

```
Error in `[<-.H2OFrame`(`*tmp*`, O, value = <environment>) : 
  `row` must be missing or a numeric vector
```

I really want to know how to figure out this.
Could you help me?

Or other package recommendation for making SHAP plot with h2o model is also Okay.

Answer (score 1):

H2O can do it's own SHAP calculations for DRF, GBM and XGBoost models. Here is an example:

```
prostate <- h2o.importFile("http://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/prostate/prostate.csv")

# Set the predictors and response; set the factors:
prostate$CAPSULE <- as.factor(prostate$CAPSULE)
splits <- h2o.splitFrame(prostate,ratios=c(0.6,0.2),seed=1234)
train <- splits[[1]]
valid <- splits[[2]]
test <- splits[[3]]
predictors <- c("ID", "AGE", "RACE", "DPROS", "DCAPS", "PSA", "VOL", "GLEASON")
response <- "CAPSULE"

# Build and train the model:
pros_gbm <- h2o.gbm(x = predictors,
                    y = response,
                    nfolds = 5,
                    seed = 1111,
                    keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                    training_frame = train)


pred <- predict_contributions.H2OModel(pros_gbm, train)
```

^ `pred` will return the SHAP values for your dataset; which it sounds like that's what you are asking for.

Also, check out [H2O's Model Explainability](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/explain.html). You can create a SHAP summary plot:

```
exp <- h2o.explain(pros_gbm, test)
exp$shap_summary
```

[image]